# How to Apply a Function to Increasing Subsets of a List (works like Accumulate)

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to find an efficient method to generalize how the function Accumulate works.

An example should make it clear:

```
x=Range[10];
Accumulate[x]

Out[36]= {1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55}
```

which can be replicated by:

```
Plus @@@ Table[Take[x, i], {i, Length@x}]

Out[35]= {1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55}
```

More generally, for any function f, what I want is a more efficient and elegant way of doing this:

```
 f @@@ Table[Take[x, i], {i, Length@x}]

Out[34]= {f[1], f[1, 2], f[1, 2, 3], f[1, 2, 3, 4], f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
 f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 
 f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
 f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}
```

It looks like something that could be handled with FoldList or ArrayFilter, but I don't see how:  I want f[1,2] not f[f[1],2].  That happens to work for f = Plus, but it won't necessarily work for other functions.

For example, suppose we want to produce a list of standardized values, but we only want to use the prior data to calculate the mean and standard deviation.

```
RepeatedTiming[
 Prepend[Last /@ 
    Standardize @@@ Table[{Take[x, i]}, {i, 2, Length@x}], 0] // N]

Out[60]= {0.00105957, {0., 0.707107, 1., 1.1619, 1.26491, 1.33631, 
  1.38873, 1.42887, 1.46059, 1.4863}}
```

or

```
RepeatedTiming[
 Prepend[Last /@ 
    Standardize @@@ List /@ Rest@Rest@FoldList[Append, {}, x] // N, 0]]

Out[84]= {0.00106662, {0, 0.707107, 1., 1.1619, 1.26491, 1.33631, 
  1.38873, 1.42887, 1.46059, 1.4863}}
```

or

```
RepeatedTiming[
 Prepend[Last /@ 
    Standardize @@@ List /@ Reverse@NestList[Most, x, Length@x - 2] //
    N, 0]]

Out[109]= {0.00105479, {0, 0.707107, 1., 1.1619, 1.26491, 1.33631, 
  1.38873, 1.42887, 1.46059, 1.4863}}
```

Can anyone improve on the syntax and/or speed of these expressions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**

```
alist = Range[10];
ReplaceList[alist, {b__, c___} :> {b}]
```

> {{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4,
> 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {1, 2, 3, 4,
> 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}

```
AbsoluteTiming[(f @@@ ReplaceList[alist, {b__, c___} :> {b}])

> {0.0000941792, {f[1], f[1, 2], f[1, 2, 3], f[1, 2, 3, 4],    f[1, 2,
> 3, 4, 5], f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],    f[1, 2, 3,
> 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],    f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
> 7, 8, 9, 10]}}
```

This timing will worsen depending on what the function is doing and the length of the list.

More succinctly and elegantly, the following generates the same output:

```
ReplaceList[alist, {b__, c___} :> f@b]
```

---

**Original**

```
x = Range[10];
Accumulate[x] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {4.96791*10^-7, {1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55}}

```
FoldList[#1 + #2 &, x] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {4.13332*10^-6, {1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55}}

---

**Using `Sow`:**

```
x = Range[10];

Last@Reap@Scan[Sow[f @@ #] &, Range[x]] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.0000291362, {{f[1], f[1, 2], f[1, 2, 3], f[1, 2, 3, 4],     f[1, 2,
> 3, 4, 5], f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],     f[1, 2, 3,
> 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],     f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
> 7, 8, 9, 10]}}}

---

Comment: RepeatedTiming[FoldList[Plus, 0, x]]

Out[38]= {2.63173*10^-6, {0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55}}

Comment: RepeatedTiming[Plus @@@ Table[Take[x, i], {i, Length@x}]]

Out[39]= {0.0000197784, {1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55}}

Comment: So FoldList is faster

Comment: Minor changes can create differences in performance while using Mathematica. It depends on your application.

Comment: Hi, there is something I could not understand. I compared the timing of your `ReplaceList` method with the timing of the `NestList` method in my answer. Using a `testlist=Range[10^4]` and prior to using f@@@  (so just the nested list),  the `NestList` method was 6 times faster than using `ReplaceList`. However, once f@@@ is used the `ReplaceList` method was 2 times faster. It seems that somehow, although the nested lists look the same, they are internally coded differently. To verify I used `On["Packing"]` to check for array unpacking. I found that `f@@@` unpacks each list one at a time with

Comment: `NestList` and with `ReplaceList` f@@@ somehow only unpacks the big 10^4 array.

Comment: Using f/@ instead of f@@@, the `NestList` method does not unpack the array it seems but the `ReplaceList` method does unpack the array.

Comment: I believe someone knowledgeable in optimization of such list structures will add another answer. If successively larger sublists are to be generated, a `Table` command suffices.

Answer (score 4):

```
n = 5;
testlist = Range[n];
f @@@ Reverse@NestList[Most, #, Length@# - 1] &@testlist

{f[1], f[1, 2], f[1, 2, 3], f[1, 2, 3, 4], f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Or

```
f @@@ Reverse@NestWhileList[Most, testlist, Length@# > 1 &]
```

Or with a symbolic function that does not evaluate to anything (for the fun of playing with `Slot` and using `Accumulate`)

```
Function[Evaluate[ReplaceAll[Plus -> Sequence][
f /@ Accumulate[Slot /@ Range[Length@testlist]]]]] @@ testlist
```

Answer (score 0):

Proposal 1:

```
f@@@Rest[FoldList[Append,{},{a,b,c,d}]]
(* {f[a],f[a,b],f[a,b,c],f[a,b,c,d]} *)
```

Proposal 2:

```
Rest[FoldList[Append,f[],{a,b,c,d}]]
(* {f[a],f[a,b],f[a,b,c],f[a,b,c,d]} *)
```

But proposal 2 will not work if `f` evaluates to something.

---

Since OP mentions standardization as an example, I think that is a case where I would not use this kind of function, instead something like

```
runningMean[x_]:=Accumulate[x]/Range[1,Length[x]];
runningVar[x_]:=(runningMean[x^2]-runningMean[x]^2)*Join[{1},Range[2,Length[x]]/Range[1,Length[x]-1]];
runningStandardize[x_]:=Join[{0},(Rest[x]-Rest[runningMean[x]])/Sqrt[Rest[runningVar[x]]]];
```

For long lists this will be faster than the approach suggested in the post.

Comment: I wouldn't class that as being any more "elegant" that my own solution, but is it any faster, I wonder?

Comment: As long as `f` is not specified, one is just building up a big expression. What does efficiency mean then? What do you want to apply this to, lists of numbers? What are the `f` you have in mind?

Comment: I just find it strange that there isn't a generalized way to replicate the functionality of Accumulate for functions other than Plus.  A good example of  where this would be useful is e.g. Standardize.  You want to generate a list of standardized values using the mean and variance of the prior data (not for the entire list).

Comment: Something like Prepend[Last /@ Standardize@@@Table[Take[x,i],{i,2,Length@x}],0]

Comment: There is a function, in the repository, called `AccumulateApply` which seems to do what you (OP) are looking for.

Comment: I have amended the question to show examples using Standardize

Comment: Unfortunately AccumulateApply works only for the simplest type of function like Plus - ResourceFunction["AccumulateApply"][Mean, x]  fails, for example

Comment: @MMAUser `Rest[FoldList[Append,f[],{a,b,c,d}]]` is the most general way to do this, but depending on the function there are better ways. The thing about Plus is that it's special in that it's associative (i.e., `Plus[Plus[a,b], c] === Plus[a,b,c]`). That's what makes `Accumulate` more efficient than a fold with an arbitrary function. To make something like this work with something like averages, you need a special function that can update running averages.