Two argument pure function -- how to replace With[]?
The below example works as intended:
SeedRandom[12345];
Sort[100*RandomReal[1, 50], Less];
SeedRandom[23456];
Sort[100*RandomReal[1, 50], Less];

Append[{%}, %%%];

With[{x = #}, 
   Take[%[[x - 1]], #] & /@ Range@Length@%[[x - 1]]] & /@ {2, 3}

I'm iteratively taking the first n elements of the list of numbers for later computation. Suppose I would want to use a CurryApplied[] construct instead of this ugly With[], how would I go about that?

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274976/how-to-apply-a-function-to-increasing-subsets-of-a-list-works-like-accumulate

This produces the same result in a more functional way:
SeedRandom[12345];
Sort[100*RandomReal[1, 50], Less];
SeedRandom[23456];
Sort[100*RandomReal[1, 50], Less];

Append[{%}, %%%];

Map[MapAt[List,1] /* FoldList[List /* Flatten], %]


CurryApplied[Take, 2][data[[# - 1]]] /@ Range@Length@data[[# - 1]] & /@ {2, 3} 

where
SeedRandom[12345];
Sort[100*RandomReal[1, 50], Less];
SeedRandom[23456];
Sort[100*RandomReal[1, 50], Less];

data = Append[{%}, %%%];

required = 
  With[{x = #}, 
     Take[%[[x - 1]], #] & /@ Range@Length@%[[x - 1]]] & /@ {2, 3};

(CurryApplied[Take, 2][data[[# - 1]]] /@ 
     Range@Length@data[[# - 1]] & /@ {2, 3}) == required

(* True *)


This doesn't use CurryApplied, but it's a simpler way to get your expected result:
data =
  {SeedRandom[23456]; Sort[100*RandomReal[1, 50], Less],
   SeedRandom[12345]; Sort[100*RandomReal[1, 50], Less]}

Array[Take[data, All, #] &, Length@data[[1]]] // Transpose

If the sublists are not the same length, you could do this:
data =
  {SeedRandom[23456]; Sort[100*RandomReal[1, 5], Less],
   SeedRandom[12345]; Sort[100*RandomReal[1, 4], Less]}
(* {{8.36267, 36.7389, 49.3038, 65.1592, 87.0372}, 
    {12.1246, 32.9922, 43.0168, 78.2753}} *)

With[
  {trdata = Flatten[data, {2}]},
  Flatten[Array[Take[trdata, #] &, Length@trdata], {3}]]

(* {{{8.36267}, 
     {8.36267, 36.7389}, 
     {8.36267, 36.7389, 49.3038}, 
     {8.36267, 36.7389, 49.3038, 65.1592}, 
     {8.36267, 36.7389, 49.3038, 65.1592, 87.0372}},
    {{12.1246}, 
     {12.1246, 32.9922}, 
     {12.1246, 32.9922, 43.0168}, 
     {12.1246, 32.9922, 43.0168, 78.2753}, 
     {12.1246, 32.9922, 43.0168, 78.2753}}} *)

But that only works if the longer sublist is first.
Or, a version using FoldList:
FoldList[Append, Take[#, 1], Rest[#]] & /@ data

Comments about CurryApplied
I've been trying to come up with a way to demonstrate CurryApplied for this, and I just don't think CurryApplied gives any benefit here. I think I see where you're coming from. You have two arguments but they come from different functions, so you're probably thinking that CurryApplied will help you "hold" one argument while you deal with the other. But the problem is that it's not easy to get your two arguments independently. To make CurryApplied work reasonably, you'll probably want to compute the arguments ahead of time anyway. I think your best bet is to re-conceive the problem along the lines of one of the answers suggested.
Update
Per the comment by user1066, we can pretty easily use CurryApplied as the function in the Array:
Array[CurryApplied[Take, 3][data][All], Length@data[[1]]] // Transpose

I guess I got wrapped around the axle of trying to use CurryApplied at the top level.
